# Filtering by value list in OData service

Tags: java, sql, odata, olingo

So, suppose I have a an SQL table:

```
create table Person(id varchar2(255) not null);
```

I'm trying to wrap it using Apache Olingo.

Is it possible to express this SQL query in OData??

```
select * from Person where id in ('a1', 'a2', 'a3', ... 'an');
```

My first try was to use a multiple `OR` filter, like so:

```
http://myserver:8080/odata/Person?$filter=(id eq '0000022AC58540EA') or (id eq '00001CD8D55ED552') or (id eq ‘000027F7F21A6196')
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
<error>
  <code/>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">
    Invalid filter expression: '(id eq '0000022AC58540EA') or (id eq '00001CD8D55ED552') or (id eq ‘000027F7F21A6196')'.
  </message>
</error>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200977/webapi-2-odata-filter-not-working) suggests using a combination of AND and ANY predicates to more or less achieve the same effect. Is this there another way to translate the aforementioned SQL query?

Thanks!

Comment: The query based on "eq" and "or" should work. It's the correct syntax. Which library are you using to implement your service?

Comment: @YiDing see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yi commented, the query is perfectly fine, I believe you get the error because you used the wrong single quote in your last or statement:

```
  ‘000027F7F21A6196'
//^
```

Comment: Ah d*mmit... OK so clearly, it's time to get a good shot of Ethiopian coffee hehehe. Thanks!